# Cryptic Family Reunion #3

Tags: cryptic-clues

I've had some growing pains with these, so thanks to those of you who have stuck with me. I am reading the comments, and trying to adjust as I make additional puzzles. I have changed up the presentation a bit in response.

As before, the answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in **alphabetical order**, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. One clue has a very slight deviation from this presentation, but once you figure the solution, I'm sure you'll be able to keep up. I hope you enjoy!

1. Step-granddad once removed limits from her after declining to restrain? (5)
2. Daughter was fashionable in the past (7)
3. Floating around New York, Katie left note for Dad (5)
4. Kylie primed to finish everything for Auntie (7)
5. Mom's call sign is Mike Echo Yank Foxtrot (3)
6. Auntie goes off on Turkey (8)
7. Head smacked after coming over to irritate Grandma (4)
8. Daughter starts neither of Rob's two Hondas (5)
9. Son pals around with top men (5)
10. Son brings mimosa in the house (5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme is:

> **members of the Kardashian clan**

Explanation:

> 1. CURB< + hEr -- BRUCE
>  2. CHIC + AGO -- CHICAGO
>  3. KAtie + NY + E -- KANYE 
>  4. K_ + END + ALL -- KENDALL
>  5. (MIKE - E)* -- KIM 
>  6. onturkey* -- KOURTNEY 
>  7. irk< + S_ -- KRIS 
>  8. NeitherOfRobsTwoHondas (intials) -- NORTH 
>  9. PALS* + M_ -- PSALM 
>  10. hidden mimoSA IN The -- SAINT

Note:

> As caught by @El-Guest, with this puzzle, the family roles in the clues actually have a relevance to the answers, when viewed from the perspective of the Kim-Kanye nuclear family (e.g., Kris is the "grandma" to Kim's children).

Comment: Well, you get a +1 just for knowing the Kardashian family tree.

Comment: @long - I should get a minus 5 for knowing that!!

Comment: Was the deviation adding 'Kylie' to clue 4?

Comment: I think the deviation is that Kendall is a step-aunt rather than an aunt; all others (Bruce = step-grandpa, Kris = Grandma, Kim = mom, Kanye = dad) are clued correctly.

Comment: @El-Guest - Good catch on the family roles. I missed that. Actually, though, Kendall and Kim have the same mother, so it is not a step relationship.

Comment: @LannyStrack oops, I meant half-aunt? They’re half-sisters, not full sisters. At any rate, I think that’s still the very slight deviation.

Comment: Crushed that one! Trying to not give offense, Caitlyn Jenner is no longer a step-granddad...but was a step-granddad once. In my mind, the definition part of that clue was "Step-granddad once", which is a slight deviation from the "rules". But clearly that didn't cause any confusion. For the record, my college-aged daughter was a big help constructing this one.